# Download CSV from API Call in Python 3 with Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-requests, decode

Im connecting to a third party site to try and download data that is specific to my company. I am posting the required fields and the file is genereated, however, the URL to where the csv is located doesnt have .csv in the link. When I try to get the contents of the site, its only 'b'\xef\xbb\xbf''

```
download = r.get('http://XXXXXapi-b.XXXstage.com/reporting/Reports?id='+str(requestID), auth=('XXXXX','XXXXX'))
print(download)
print(download.headers)
print(download.content)
content = download.content
print(content.decode('UTF-8'))
```

the request Id was defined earlier when the request was submitted.

The repsonses I get:

`Response [200]`

```
{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content- Length': '3', 'Content-Type': 'text/csv', 'Expires': '-1', 
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=Report.csv', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Date': 'Thu, 14 Jun 2018 14:17:46 GMT'}
```

`b'\xef\xbb\xbf'`

-

Am I looking at this incorrectly? Does that content need to be decoded,is there even content? Is the content length mean that there are really only 3 results. Finally, is there a way to download the csv from this get or should the csv data be in the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a look at the response:

- Code `200` says that the server reports a successful processing
- `Content-Type: text/csv` says that the returned content is CSV
  formatted
- `Content-Length: 3` says that the content is 3 bytes long

3 bytes seems short for a CSV, and the content (that you access using wsodownload.content) is indeed some non-printable characters.

So it looks like there is nothing wrong with your request, but the servers returns an invalid response.

BTW, you can use a proper way to pass arguments as query string, using the `params` parameter to `requests.get()`:

```
requests.get('http://XXXXapi-b.XXXXstage.com/reporting/Reports', params={'id': requestID}, auth=('XXXX','XXXX'))
```

Comment: Please consider changing your authentication details in case those are real ones

Comment: ah thanks! So in this situation, you would expect to see the results of the csv when I pass the download.content command correct? Even though I havent downloaded the physical csv?

Comment: By default `requests` takes care of downloading the response for you when you access .`content` on the response. So if the server response was correct `.content` whould contain the full text of the csv. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow